# Can’t create table in YugabyteDB cluster

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I have a query, I see the log file on the leader is filling with these lines continuously

```
I0110 11:28:47.117158 17899 cluster_balance.cc:1210] Processing tablet af97f8fae2f44926867cac4614da96f2
I0110 11:28:47.117162 17899 cluster_balance.cc:1210] Processing tablet ba80a09979ab4504a0fe2a39afba9550
I0110 11:28:47.117166 17899 cluster_balance.cc:1210] Processing tablet bd86eae8eceb4c0b9afff55752ca5e6c
```

and create table command  is resulting in this

```
ERROR:  Invalid argument: Error creating table system_postgres.sequences_data on the master: Not enough tablet servers in aws:us-east:us-east-1d. Need at least 1 but only have 0.
```

What could be wrong?

Here are the configs for the deployment:

01-master

```
--master_addresses=172.16.20.76:7100,172.16.41.29:7100,172.16.7.24:7100
--rpc_bind_addresses=172.16.7.24:7100
--webserver_interface=172.16.7.24
--fs_data_dirs=/opt/yugabytedb/data
--log_dir=/mnt/log/yugabytedb
--placement_cloud=aws
--placement_region=us-east-1
--placement_zone=us-east-1b
```

02-master

```
--master_addresses=172.16.20.76:7100,172.16.41.29:7100,172.16.7.24:7100
--rpc_bind_addresses=172.16.20.76:7100
--webserver_interface=172.16.20.76
--fs_data_dirs=/opt/yugabytedb/data
--log_dir=/mnt/log/yugabytedb
--placement_cloud=aws
--placement_region=us-east-1
--placement_zone=us-east-1c
Abhishek A  3 days ago
03-master
--master_addresses=172.16.20.76:7100,172.16.41.29:7100,172.16.7.24:7100
--rpc_bind_addresses=172.16.41.29:7100
--webserver_interface=172.16.41.29
--fs_data_dirs=/opt/yugabytedb/data
--log_dir=/mnt/log/yugabytedb
--placement_cloud=aws
--placement_region=us-east-1
--placement_zone=us-east-1d
```

01-tserver

```
--tserver_master_addrs=172.16.20.76:7100,172.16.41.29:7100,172.16.7.24:7100
--rpc_bind_addresses=172.16.7.24:9100
--fs_data_dirs=/opt/yugabytedb/data
--log_dir=/mnt/log/yugabytedb
--placement_cloud=aws
--placement_region=us-east-1
--placement_zone=us-east-1b
--pgsql_proxy_bind_address=172.16.7.24:5433
--pgsql_proxy_bind_address=127.0.0.1:5433
--enable_ysql
```

02-tserver

```
--tserver_master_addrs=172.16.20.76:7100,172.16.41.29:7100,172.16.7.24:7100
--rpc_bind_addresses=172.16.20.76:9100
--fs_data_dirs=/opt/yugabytedb/data
--log_dir=/mnt/log/yugabytedb
--placement_cloud=aws
--placement_region=us-east-1
--placement_zone=us-east-1c
--pgsql_proxy_bind_address=172.16.20.76:5433
--pgsql_proxy_bind_address=127.0.0.1:5433
--enable_ysql
```

03-tserver

```
--tserver_master_addrs=172.16.20.76:7100,172.16.41.29:7100,172.16.7.24:7100
--rpc_bind_addresses=172.16.41.29:9100
--fs_data_dirs=/opt/yugabytedb/data
--log_dir=/mnt/log/yugabytedb
--placement_cloud=aws
--placement_region=us-east-1
--placement_zone=us-east-1d
--pgsql_proxy_bind_address=172.16.41.29:5433
--pgsql_proxy_bind_address=127.0.0.1:5433
--enable_ysql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The region in your config is `us-east-1` but it seems to be looking for `us-east` in the error.

Run this command:

```
./bin/yb-admin \
    --master_addresses 172.151.17.130:7100,172.151.17.220:7100,172.151.17.140:7100 \
    modify_placement_info  \
    aws.us-west.us-west-2a,aws.us-west.us-west-2b,aws.us-west.us-west-2c 3
```

to include -1 for the region names and then create the table.